# Before inserting a record in the database to validate that there is

Tags: android, sqlite

Before inserting a record in the database to validate that there is, for example I have a table that has two fields, table fields VA with Customer, First, I want to validate the field if there is no customer registration and if there insert

That i want to do in android using Sqlite

Comment: And whats your question? :)

Comment: I want to validate that this record is not duplicated

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = '" + id + "'";
Cursor data = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

After this check by following code

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // record exists
} else {
    // record not found
}
```

Comment: can give me a more detailed example?

Comment: in your select query, `id` will be replaced with your column name, and cursor will be created and `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` will move to first record. so you can identify whether any record you have or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities :

1)make a select to check if there is the same key in database, then insert or update.

2)make directly an update. update will return the number of row updated, if the number is 0, so you can do an insert.

Answer (score 0):

Look at SQLite constraints. This really isn't Android-specific; it's a feature of SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
String[] args = { myDataToCheck };
c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,
                    myColumnToCheck + "=?", args, null, null,  null);
            if (c.getCount() == 0) {
// doesn't exists 
 }else{
//exists
}
```